# How to generate samples of uniform random variable and count how many times 2*mean is greater than upper parameter

Tags: r

I don't know how to write the code to generate 1000 experiments of a uniform random variable between 0 and 10 with 10 data points such that it counts and returns to me how many times twice the mean of the sample points is greater than 10 and was hoping for some help with it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
results <- rep(x=0,times=1000)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  dat <- runif(n=10,min=0,max=10)
  if(mean(dat) >= 5) {
    results[[i]] <- 1
  }
}
sum(results)
```

Comment: I suppose this could also be written as `n = 1000; m = matrix(runif(n*10, 0, 10), nr=n); sum(rowMeans(m) > 5)` which will likely be faster (as long as `n` is not so large as to cause memory issues)

Comment: @user2957945 Yes, that would be a better implementation. It looks like that is about 10x faster.